# New site collection is empty? SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint

I use the central administration to create a new site colletion and when I have entered all the required information and click OK it takes a while then I get a confirmation message that the new site collection has been created. I click on the link but when I go there the site collections is empty (no menues no pages no nothing) and I don't get an error message, it's just a blank page with no code.

What can I be doing wrong here? I know I set the site collection owner to my user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what site template are you using? are there any errors in the ULS/windows logs when you do the create?

Comment: publishing portal, just downloaded the ULS viewer to check the logs and I see now that it says no document template uploaded for list resources:core,themegallerylist - none found for list template. applying web template  BLANKINTERNETCONTAINER on web url http://server/sites/test, this might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you say, "I set the site collection owner to my user," is "my user" your login or another user who you are creating the site collection for?

If it is the latter, that could be your problem. By default, the home page of a Publishing Portal site collection is checked out. If you do not have permissions to view drafts, then it is possible that you could see a blank page because there is no published version of the page available. If this is the case, either add yourself to the site collection administrators group or have the other user publish the home page.